# Extracting information from a website with the 'Mechanize' Ruby gem

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am running a service where users can track their parcels from various couriers. Now I am adding a courier who does not have an API where I can read the tracking information. So I will use the mechanize gem to fetch directly from their website. However, the information that I am looking for is no where to be found.

The sample URL:

http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx?view=item&itemid=00257059831553798878

EDIT:

The above URL sometimes redirects to a main page, so use this one instead:

http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx?view=item&itemid=00257059831553798878000257059831553798878

The information I want to extract is:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td>6/19/2013 10:10 AM</td><td>Døgnposten 339 Dognposten, Denmark</td><td>The shipment item has been delivered</td>
</tr>
```

Or to be more precise, I want the delivery status and date:

**6/19/2013 10:10 AM** and **The shipment item has been delivered**

Could anyone help?

My code:

```
require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx?view=item&itemid=00257059831553798878")
pp page # =>

#<Mechanize::Page
 {url
  #<URI::HTTP:0x007f985a853b90 URL:http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title "\r\n\t\r\n\tHome\r\n\r\n"}
 {iframes #<Mechanize::Page::Frame nil "">}
 {frames}
 {links
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Turn on more accessible mode" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Turn off more accessible mode" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Skip Ribbon Commands" "javascript:;">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Skip to main content" "javascript:;">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "javascript:;">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n                            \r\n                            På dansk                            \r\n                        "
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/da">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n                            \r\n                            About us                            \r\n                        "
   "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "About us" "/en/Om%20os/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Company presentation"
   "/en/Om%20os/Virksomheden/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Investor relations"
   "/en/Om%20os/Investor%20relations/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Quality" "/en/Om%20os/kvalitet/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Business partners"
   "/en/Om%20os/Business%20partners/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Our responsibility"
   "/en/Om%20os/CSR/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Press" "/en/Om%20os/Presse/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n                            \r\n                            Webshop                            \r\n                        "
   "http://www2.postdanmark.dk/netbutik">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n                            \r\n                            På dansk                            \r\n                        "
   "/da/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Log in" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Try Again"
   "javascript: PostenCos.Login.SetLoginFrame()">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "{Username}"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Log out" "/_layouts/signout.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Private" "/en/Privat">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Business communication" "/en/Erhvervspost">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Market communication" "/en/Kommunikation">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Logistics" "/en/Logistik">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Track and traceCurrently selected"
   "/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "see list over countries"
   "/en/tracktrace/Pages/List-over-countries.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "see list over countries"
   "/da/Documents/Lister/landeliste-track-and-trace.pdf">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Item ID" "javascript:void(0)">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Reference" "javascript:void(0)">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Cell phone number" "javascript:void(0)">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" nil>
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n                    How may I help you?\r\n                    "
   "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n                        \r\n                    "
   "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "javascript:openNewWindow();">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "skrivpost@post.dk" "mailto:skrivpost@post.dk">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Temp QF" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "{0}" nil>
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Find postal code and address" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Advanced search" "http://www.postdanmark.dk">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "{0}" nil>
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Track item" "#">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Advanced search" "http://www.postdanmark.dk">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "{0}" nil>
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n            "
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Contact us"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/kontakt_os/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Private" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Privat">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Letters"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Privat/Breve/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Parcels"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Privat/Pakker/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Stamps" "https://www2.postdanmark.dk/netbutik/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "More" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Privat">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Business Communication"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Erhvervspost">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Letters"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Erhvervspost/Breve/Pages/Lettersize.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "E-services"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Erhvervspost/E-services/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Newspapers"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Erhvervspost/Newspapers/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Outsourcing"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Erhvervspost/Outsourcing/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "More" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Erhvervspost">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Market Communication"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Kommunikation">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Direct Mail"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Kommunikation/Direct%20Marketing/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Electronic Communication"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Kommunikation/Electronic%20Communication/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Customer Dialogue and CRM"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Kommunikation/Customer%20dialogue%20and%20CRM/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "More" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Kommunikation">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Logistics" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Logistik">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "Express" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Logistik/">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Pallets"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Logistik/Pallets/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Parcels"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Logistik/Pakker/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link
   "Outsourcing"
   "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Logistik/Outsourcing/Pages/home.aspx">
  #<Mechanize::Page::Link "More" "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Logistik">}
 {forms
  #<Mechanize::Form
   {name "aspnetForm"}
   {method "POST"}
   {action "home.aspx"}
   {fields
    [hidden:0x3fcc29776818 type: hidden name: MSOWebPartPage_PostbackSource value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977b098 type: hidden name: MSOTlPn_SelectedWpId value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977bafc type: hidden name: MSOTlPn_View value: 0]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977b840 type: hidden name: MSOTlPn_ShowSettings value: False]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977b69c type: hidden name: MSOGallery_SelectedLibrary value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977b084 type: hidden name: MSOGallery_FilterString value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977a558 type: hidden name: MSOTlPn_Button value: none]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977a134 type: hidden name: __REQUESTDIGEST value: 0x8B33445463DA37BF0185122BE4E290417418500A6E4C5D921650824C35A1F2584F6F044F07E59417B78428E2CDAF0A6D389D2517035D845DA3577782124BA2F7,13 Jul 2013 19:19:04 -0000]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977f8dc type: hidden name: MSOSPWebPartManager_DisplayModeName value: Browse]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977f5bc type: hidden name: MSOSPWebPartManager_ExitingDesignMode value: false]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977ed74 type: hidden name: MSOWebPartPage_Shared value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977e9a0 type: hidden name: MSOLayout_LayoutChanges value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977e5cc type: hidden name: MSOLayout_InDesignMode value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc2977e180 type: hidden name: _wpSelected value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc29783f7c type: hidden name: _wzSelected value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc29783d74 type: hidden name: MSOSPWebPartManager_OldDisplayModeName value: Browse]
    [hidden:0x3fcc29783bd0 type: hidden name: MSOSPWebPartManager_StartWebPartEditingName value: false]
    [hidden:0x3fcc297837ac type: hidden name: MSOSPWebPartManager_EndWebPartEditing value: false]
    [hidden:0x3fcc29782668 type: hidden name: __VIEWSTATE value: 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]
    [hidden:0x3fcc29787b54 type: hidden name: __EVENTVALIDATION value: /wEWFwLGnsKEAwKBgqvxBwKBgqvxBwK9oKb6AwLa0YKXCwLa0YKXCwLUv+TNAQLUv+TNAQLAxJ+cBAL+ovynDgLPotSnDgLAouynDgL4ooSnDgK2m+ugAgK2m+ugAgKg6ozjDgKg6ozjDgLLm7G2BQK/j979BAL/2MOKCALs5afrBwLrj4vzCQLrqPiWC56EDyaGeVoGZe8PmhJFVpzd/YLV]
    [text:0x3fcc2978780c type: text name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$txtShipmentId value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc29786c68 type: text name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$txtReference value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc29786330 type: text name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$txtProductionNumber value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc2978ba24 type: text name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$txtSmsNumber value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc2978b1dc type: text name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$txtSmsNotification value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc2978e8dc type: text name: nw_pc_qf_addressField value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc2978e47c type: text name: nw_pc_qf_cityField value: ]
    [text:0x3fcc297934e0 type: text name: nw_ntt_qf_itemIdField value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc297929b4 type: hidden name: _wpcmWpid value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc29796b40 type: hidden name: wpcmVal value: ]
    [selectlist:0x3fcc2979fcf4 type:  name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$ddlCountryCode value: DK]}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons
    [submit:0x3fcc297873ac type: submit name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$btnSearchShipment value: Search]
    [submit:0x3fcc2978beac type: submit name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$btnSearchReference value: Search]
    [submit:0x3fcc2978fbec type: submit name: ctl00$m$g_9d0e16ab_1842_411b_81f3_f2e7cba6e233$ctl00$btnSearchSMS value: Search]
    [imagebutton:0x3fcc2978ebfc type: image name:  value: ]
    [button:0x3fcc29793d50 type: button name: nw_pc_qf_searchButton value: Search]
    [button:0x3fcc29792fcc type: button name: nw_ntt_qf_searchButton value: Search]
    [button:0x3fcc297a7b20 type:  name:  value: ]}>
  #<Mechanize::Form
   {name nil}
   {method "GET"}
   {action "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/Pages/Search.aspx"}
   {fields
    [hidden:0x3fcc297aeca4 type: hidden name: k value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fcc297ae8f8 type: hidden name: s value: dk_en]}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons}>}>
```

Comment: Remove the Mechanize object from the question. It's TL;DR. Replace it with SUMMARIZED HTML that shows the chain of tags leading to the content you want. If that content is not in the HTML then Mechanize can not help you.

Comment: Very sorry, but I don't understand your instructions?

Comment: You can't get to it with a `get`, you need to submit the form.

Comment: To get better answers, you'll need to post an HTML snippet containing the text you want to extract. No need to post the Mechanize object, it's not useful.

Comment: Using [HTTPClient](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient) to `get 'http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx?view=item&itemid=00257059831553798878000257059831553798878'` results in a 302 redirect to `http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx`

Comment: @theTinMan Evidently the tracking ID expired, so we'd need another one to see the appropriate HTML ourselves. Another reason the HTML should be posted in the question.

Comment: This fails the http://sscce.org/ guidelines.

Comment: I apologize, but I am not sure what you mean. Should I put in the html of the page I want to scrape? Regardless, you are right that the URL seem to expire. What I do is that I go to the tracking page "http://www.postdanmark.dk/en/tracktrace/Pages/home.aspx" and enter the tracking number "00257059831553798878".